# JQuery - Android - The 'Keyup' Event Does Not Work On Backspace In Chrome

Tags: android, jquery, jquery-events, keyup

I am wondering why the backspace/ delete button does not detect a keyup event in jQuery.

I find this odd as it is useful and should be supported. Are there any alternatives to this?

This is only happening in Android - Chrome.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can actually fix this by attaching an event listener to the input.

```
var inputBox = document.getElementById('inputId');

inputBox.addEventListener(‘input’, function() {
    exampleFunc();
}, false);
```

Cheers

Comment: Based for this, I used the jQuery counterpart $('#inputId').on('input', function() { exampleFunc(); }); and it works like a charm :) Thanks!